# Hiding Tikz nodes behind eachother

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-node

I want to create a cube consisting of smaller cubes in particular color patterns. It seems to me loops are very useful here, but I get nodes drawn through eachother. Is there a way to tell tikz to not draw nodes that are hidden by nodes sitting in front of them? I am trying to achieve something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  redCube/.pic={
    \draw[fill=red!20] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=red!50] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
  }
}
\tikzset{
  yellowCube/.pic={
    \draw[fill=yellow!20] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=yellow!50] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sizea}{2}
\newcommand{\sizeb}{2}
\newcommand{\sizec}{2}


\tikz[z={(0.4, 0.4)}]
\path
\foreach \a in {0, ..., \sizea} {
    \foreach \b in {0, ..., \sizeb} {
        \foreach \c in {0, ..., \sizec} {
            (2*\a,\b,\c)pic{redCube}
            (2*\a + 1, \b, \c)pic{yellowCube}
        }
    }
};

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

Tikz unfortunately doesn't offer a method for [hidden-surface determination](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hidden-surface_determination), so you have to make manual adjustments here.

In your case you could just draw the cubes in the correct order by rearranging the for loops and reverse the order for `\c` (the z coordinate) using `{\sizec, ..., 0}`. So it is drawn from the back to the front on top of each other.

For more complex examples you can also use layers, see:

- [CTAN: Package pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), 3.13 "Using Layers: The Background Rectangles"
- [CTAN: Package tikz-layers](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-layers)

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  redCube/.pic={
    \draw[fill=red!20] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=red!50] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
  }
}
\tikzset{
  yellowCube/.pic={
    \draw[fill=yellow!20] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=yellow!50] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sizea}{2}
\newcommand{\sizeb}{2}
\newcommand{\sizec}{2}


\tikz[z={(0.4, 0.4)}]
\path
\foreach \c in {\sizec, ..., 0} {
    \foreach \a in {0, ..., \sizea} {
        \foreach \b in {0, ..., \sizeb} {
            (2*\a,\b,\c)pic{redCube}
            (2*\a + 1, \b, \c)pic{yellowCube}
        }
    }
};

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]